# Feature selection - how to go about it when you have way too many features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Let's assume you have 1,400 columns/data points for 200k entries and your goal is to determine which of these columns show the most signal towards a simple classification task.
I've already removed columns with a threshold of null values, low variance, bad and also too many levels for categorical, and I still have 900+ columns.
I can use lasso if I only include the 500+ numerical columns, but if I try to include the categorical as well I keep crashing, it's too much data to process.
How would you go about further reducing features in that case? My goal, more than the classification itself, is to identify the features that bring in the most information towards the classification task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data driven approach, for example the most simple one would be to use the **L1 regularisation** on a **logistic regression** (with your simple classification task) and looking at the weights you select the ones that are not zero or close to zero.

Basically the L1 norm on the model weights enforces the **sparsity** of the weights vector, and in doing so, the only surviving weight are the ones corresponding to the "*important*" features.

In any case be careful and normalise the data before using this technique and also be careful about categorical and scalar features...

You can also use a Neural network, and then compute the gradient w.r.t. the input to see what influences the decision more.

Or some other technique like: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-33778-0_24

Alternatively you can also use a Random Forest model and do feature importance like: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm doing when I say I can use lasso, but it's still too many features for me to be able to run a logistic regression with both numerical and categorical features. With numerical only I can do it, but I do want to be able to look at the categorical ones as well.

Comment: @GiovannaFernandes You can also use a Neural network, and then compute the gradient w.r.t. the input to see what influences the decision more. Or some other technique like: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-33778-0_24